# invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'13 18:33:25' inserting date

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I am creating a portfolio website with a blog on it. Everyhting was working perfectly but suddenly the above mentioned error start showing up anytime I tried go to my blog link and it says ther is some thin wrong with my bootstrap css link:
this is what the error says:

```
ValueError at /blog/
invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'11 18:52:18'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/
Django Version: 3.2.7
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'11 18:52:18'
Exception Location: C:\Users\sumit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\sqlite3\dbapi2.py, line 64, in convert_date
Python Executable:  C:\Users\sumit\Desktop\portfolio\env\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.5
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\sumit\\Desktop\\portfolio\\personalportfolio',
 'C:\\Users\\sumit\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\python39.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\sumit\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\sumit\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\sumit\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39',
 'C:\\Users\\sumit\\Desktop\\portfolio\\env',
 'C:\\Users\\sumit\\Desktop\\portfolio\\env\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Sun, 19 Sep 2021 02:37:26 +0000
Error during template rendering
In template C:\Users\sumit\Desktop\portfolio\personalportfolio\portfolio\templates\portfolio\base.html, error at line 11

invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'11 18:52:18'
1   {% load static %}
2   <!doctype html>
3   <html lang="en">
4   
5   <head>
6     <!-- Required meta tags -->
7     <meta charset="utf-8">
8     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
9   
10    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
11    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
12  
13    <link rel="stylesheet" href='{% static "portfolio/custom.css" %}'>
14  
15    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
16  
17    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href='{% static "portfolio/Logo.png" %}'>
18  
19    <title>Sumit Dadwal</title>
20  </head>
21
```

[for more clarity i have also attached the image:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWHOq.png)

traceback error:

```
    Internal Server Error: /blog/
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\sumit\Desktop\portfolio\env\lib\site- 
    packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
    File "C:\Users\sumit\Desktop\portfolio\env\lib\site- 
    packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, 
    **callback_kwargs)
    File 
    "C:\Users\sumit\Desktop\portfolio\personalportfolio\blog\views.py", 
    line 7, in blog
    return render(request, 'blog/blog.html', {'posts': posts})
    File "C:\Users\sumit\Desktop\portfolio\env\lib\site- 
    packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, 
    using=using)
    File "C:\Users\sumit\Desktop\portfolio\env\lib\site- 
    packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
    File "C:\Users\sumit\Desktop\portfolio\env\lib\site- 
    packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
    File "C:\Users\sumit\Desktop\portfolio\env\lib\site- 
    packages\django\template\base.py", line 170, in render
    return self._render(context)
    File "C:\Users\sumit\Desktop\portfolio\env\lib\site- 
    packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
    File "C:\Users\sumit\Desktop\portfolio\env\lib\site- 
    packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
    File "C:\Users\sumit\Desktop\portfolio\env\lib\site- 
    packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
    File "C:\Users\sumit\Desktop\portfolio\env\lib\site- 
    packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
    File "C:\Users\sumit\Desktop\portfolio\env\lib\site- 
    packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
    File "C:\Users\sumit\Desktop\portfolio\env\lib\site- 
    packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
   File "C:\Users\sumit\Desktop\portfolio\env\lib\site- 
   packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
   File "C:\Users\sumit\Desktop\portfolio\env\lib\site- 
   packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
   File "C:\Users\sumit\Desktop\portfolio\env\lib\site- 
   packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
   File "C:\Users\sumit\Desktop\portfolio\env\lib\site- 
   packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
   File "C:\Users\sumit\Desktop\portfolio\env\lib\site- 
   packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 168, in render
    len_values = len(values)
   File "C:\Users\sumit\Desktop\portfolio\env\lib\site- 
   packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 262, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
   File "C:\Users\sumit\Desktop\portfolio\env\lib\site- 
   packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1324, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
   File "C:\Users\sumit\Desktop\portfolio\env\lib\site- 
   packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 51, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, 
   chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
   File "C:\Users\sumit\Desktop\portfolio\env\lib\site- 
   packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1175, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
   File "C:\Users\sumit\Desktop\portfolio\env\lib\site- 
   packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
   File "C:\Users\sumit\Desktop\portfolio\env\lib\site- 
   packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, 
   executor=self._execute)
   File "C:\Users\sumit\Desktop\portfolio\env\lib\site- 
   packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 75, in 
   _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
   File "C:\Users\sumit\Desktop\portfolio\env\lib\site- 
   packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
   File "C:\Users\sumit\Desktop\portfolio\env\lib\site- 
   packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 423, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
   

     File
    
    "C:\Users\sumit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\sqlite3\dbapi2.py", line 64, in convert_date
        return datetime.date(*map(int, val.split(b"-")))
    ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'11 18:52:18'
        [18/Sep/2021 18:59:06] "GET /blog/ HTTP/1.1" 500 181597
```

I have tried everything i know but still find myself stuck. I am new and still learning. let me know if anything else needs to be updated in the question.

UPDATE: I KINDA SOLVED THE PROBLEM BY REMOVING DATE_POSTED FIELD FROM MY MODELS BUT DONT KNOW WHY IT WAS STOPPING TEMPLATE FROM LOADING. BELOW IS MY MODELS CODE:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
#from django.utils import timezone

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # date_posted = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: `let me know if you need anything else to find solution` Yes, please show us the entire code traceback error message.

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code or error messages.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: It seems like in your form, you are passing a datetime to the server, which tries to parse it as a date only in a naive way.

Answer (score 2):

Sqlite3 doesn't have a native `date` type, but Python's sqlite3 module automatically register's adapter functions that will convert `date` and `datetime` objects when inserting and retrieving them into and out of the database.  Django uses this functionality when it's configured to use Sqlite.

When retrieving a date, the sqlite3 [date converter function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1f08d16c90b6619607fe0656328062ab986cce29/Lib/sqlite3/dbapi2.py#L63) assumes it will receive a bytestring of the form `b'YY-mm-dd'`, so it tries to split it on the `b'-'` to create a date object.

```
>>> import datetime as dt
>>> dt.date(*map(int, b'2021-09-26'.split(b'-')))
datetime.date(2021, 9, 26)
```

However if the value is a *datetime* bytestring, the conversion fails with the error like that from the question:

```
>>> date(*map(int, b'2021-09-26 09:16:00.000000'.split(b'-')))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'26 09:16:00.000000'
```

We can reproduce this behaviour with sqlite3:

```py
conn = sqlite3.connect('so69236477.db', detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES)

with conn:
    cur = conn.cursor()
    datetime = dt.datetime.now()
    datestring = datetime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    cur.execute("""INSERT INTO t69236477 (date_posted) VALUES (?)""", (datestring,))
    conn.commit()
    cur.execute("""SELECT date_posted FROM t69236477""")
conn.close()
```

Resulting in this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/python_projects/so38/so69236477.py", line 18, in <module>
    cur.execute("""SELECT date_posted FROM t69236477""")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 64, in convert_date
    return datetime.date(*map(int, val.split(b"-")))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'26 09:28:49'
```

So it seems that at some point the column has been populated with datetime strings instead of dates.  There are two steps to take to fix this.

- First, review your code to find locations where `date_posted` is being set, and ensure that the result is a `date`, not a `datetime`.
- Second, fix the data.  You can do this by executing this SQL statement

```sql
update t69236477 set date_posted = substr(date_posted, 11, -10)
```

substituting the name of your table for `t69236477`.  The statement replaces all `date_posted` values with their first ten characters, so just the 'YY-mm-dd' part.

You can execute the SQL in sqlite3.exe or in the Python interpreter, connecting to the database with the sqlite3 module.  Copy the database file first so that you can recover from errors if necessary.

This is how you would do it in sqlite3.exe (but on Linux).

```
$ sqlite3 so69236477.db 
SQLite version 3.28.0 2019-04-16 19:49:53
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> select date_posted from t69236477;
2021-09-26 09:37:53
sqlite> update t69236477 set date_posted = substr(date_posted, 11, -10);
sqlite> select date_posted from t69236477;
2021-09-26
```